# JavaApns log4j.apache error iPhone push notification

Tags: xcode, apple-push-notifications

I have been trying to set up a program that sends a push notification for my app. First I used 
this tutorial
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services

From this I learned how to get my device's token. 
I tried following the rest of to tutorial, but got stuck near the end, which told me to download a class named PushMeBaby, and change some lines of code and run it. However I can't even compile this application. It gives me the error:

The run destination My Mac 64-bit is not valid for Running the scheme 'PushMeBaby'.

after many hours of trying to figure this out, I decided to switch to a new tutorial, because i couldn't find a way to fix this one.

This lead me to java and a certain java class named JavaApns
http://code.google.com/p/javapns/

Inorder to install this library and to get it to work, you need to meet a few requirements
Here is where I think the problem arises. The 3rd requirement tells me to also download and install two other libraries :

bcprov-jdk15-146.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar

The first library works fine, since there is no errors. However log4 comes in a zipped file, and whenever I try to unzip it, it gives me the error "An unexpected error occurred (28)" So I just go into the zip file and only unzip the library instead of the whole file (no errors). Then I put both libraries+JavaAPNS into my project and run it with

[my code]

```
import javapns.Push;
import javapns.communication.exceptions.CommunicationException;
import javapns.communication.exceptions.KeystoreException;


public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Push.alert("Hello World!", "MyCertificate.p12", "MyPassword",false, "MyDevicetoken");
    } catch (CommunicationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeystoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


       }
}
```

Finally the error that this gives me is:
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (javapns.notification.Payload).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I went to the link `logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig`, however it doesn't really explain how to solve the problem. So if you have any ideas or suggestions ( Or you want to suggest a better library/tutorial) I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the same [link](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig) you went to:

> **Why do I see a warning about "No appenders found for logger" and "Please configure log4j properly"?**
>
> This occurs when the default configuration files log4j.properties and
>   log4j.xml can not be found and the application performs no explicit
>   configuration. log4j uses Thread.getContextClassLoader().getResource()
>   to locate the default configuration files and does not directly check
>   the file system. Knowing the appropriate location to place
>   log4j.properties or log4j.xml requires understanding the search
>   strategy of the class loader in use. log4j does not provide a default
>   configuration since output to the console or to the file system may be
>   prohibited in some environments.

Also:

> **Why can't log4j find my properties file in a J2EE or WAR application?**
>
> The short answer: the log4j classes and the properties file are not
>   within the scope of the same classloader.
>
> The long answer (and what to do about it): J2EE or Servlet containers
>   utilize Java's class loading system. Sun changed the way classloading
>   works with the release of Java 2. In Java 2, classloaders are arranged
>   in a hierarchial parent-child relationship. When a child classloader
>   needs to find a class or a resource, it first delegates the request to
>   the parent.
>
> Log4j only uses the default Class.forName() mechanism for loading
>   classes. Resources are handled similarly. See the documentation for
>   java.lang.ClassLoader for more details.
>
> So, if you're having problems, try loading the class or resource
>   yourself. If you can't find it, neither will log4j. ;)

Comment: I already read those, and i don't really understand them well...  From my understanding, you need to load into log4j.properties and log4j.xml into the project however I couldn't find them in the zip file

Comment: @A.sharif You have to _create_ a log4j.properties file for this to work. [This](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/) site has a few examples for you to get started with.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11240411/273119

The have the answer you are searching.
They say that you need to call:

```
    BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained on JavaPNS's "[Troubleshooting](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/wiki/Troubleshooting#Enable_logging)" page, you can enable logging programatically.  You do **not** need to setup the whole Log4j system with config files.